# What is the proper way to build a paragraph with OpenXML?

Tags: .net, vb.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to create a docx file based upon an existing paragraph **p**.  I'm not trying to clone the paragraph (eventually I want to modify the text before writing to **newGraph**)

```
Dim newGraph As New Paragraph
For Each r As Run In p
    newGraph.Append(r)
Next
```

Running the above code yields the following error:

> Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree.

What is the correct way of creating a new paragraph from an existing one (assuming I want to modify text along the way).

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, **an instance of `OpenXmlElement` can not be added to multiple parents.**

You can:

- clone each `Run`, modify them and then add them to your new `paragraph`.

  ```
  Dim newGraph As New Paragraph
  For Each r As Run In p
     Dim newRun = r.Clone()
     ''make some changes here
     newGraph.Append(newRun)
  Next
  ```
- or clone the entire `paragraph` and then loop into each `Run` if you want to modifiy them...

  ```
  Dim newGraph As Paragraph = Ctype(p.Clone, Paragraph)
  For Each r As Run In newGraph.Descendants(Of Run)()
     ''make some changes here

  Next
  ```

Best approach depends of what you want to do exactly (clone all attributes or not).

Remarks from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlelement.clone.aspx):

> Cloning an OpenXmlNode copies all attributes and their values,
>   including those generated by the XML processor to represent defaulted
>   attributes. This method recursively clones the node and the subtree
>   underneath it. Clone is equivalent to calling CloneNode(true).

Hope this helps.